# What is the difference between lexical and dynamic scoping in Perl?

Tags: perl, scope

As far I know, the `my` operator is to declare variables that are truly lexically scoped and dynamic scoping is done using the `local` operator to declare a variable.

Can any one describe them in brief?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **local($x)** saves away the old value of the global variable $x and
> assigns a new value for the duration of the subroutine which is
> visible in other functions called from that subroutine. This is done
> at run-time, so is called dynamic scoping. local() always affects
> global variables, also called package variables or dynamic variables.
>
> **my($x)** creates a new variable that is only visible in the current
> subroutine. This is done at compile-time, so it is called lexical or
> static scoping. my() always affects private variables, also called
> lexical variables or (improperly) static(ly scoped) variables.

Take a look at the [Perl-FAQ's](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What%27s-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-lexical-%28static%29-scoping?--Between-local%28%29-and-my%28%29?):

Comment: "my($x) creates a new variable that is only visible in the current subroutine". That is not true. `my` creates a new variable that is only visible in the current *block of code*. A subroutine is only one example of a block. You make a similar error in your definition of `local`.

Comment: @O.D: if no curly braces around `{}`, then `my` scope is whole file. And either one is current block of code for Perl.

Answer (score 11):

[MJD explained this in 1998](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Namespaces.html):

> `my` creates a local variable. `local` doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

I'll add a quick example.

```
$var = "Global";

sub inner {
    print "inner:         $var\n";
}

sub changelocal {
    my $var = "Local";
    print "changelocal:   $var\n";

    &inner
}

sub changedynamic {
    local $var = "Dynamic";
    print "changedynamic: $var\n";

    &inner
}

&inner
&changelocal
&changedynamic
```

This gives the following output (comments added).

```
inner:         Global  # Finds the global variable.
changedynamic: Dynamic # Dynamic variable overrides global.
inner:         Dynamic # Find dynamic variable now.
changelocal:   Local   # Local variable overrides global.
inner:         Global  # The local variable is not in scope so global is found.
```

You can think of a dynamic variable as a way to mask a global for functions you call.  Where as lexical scoped variables only be visible from code inside the nearest braces.