# perl: changing between line by line and as a whole

Tags: perl

I'm starting to work with perl and I need to edit some text. Sometimes I need that perl read the input line by line and sometimes I need perl read the input as a whole. I know that this can be set with something like:

```
$/ = undef;
```

or with something like:

```
{
        local $/;
        $myfile= <$MYFILE>;
}
```

But Im not sure how I have to do if, in the same script, I want to change the reading from "whole" to "line by line" or viceversa. That is, imagine a script with starts as:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $filename = shift;
open F, $filename or die "Usa: $0 FILENAME\n";
while(<F>) {
}
```

And I make some replaces (s///;). And then I need that go on with my edition but reading as a whole. So I write:

```
{
        local $/;
        $filename = <F>;
}
```

But then I need to go on reading line by line....

Somebody can explain me the logic behind this in order to learn how to 'change' from one mode to another, always keeping the last edited version of the input? Thanks

---

Ok, sorry. I will try to focus on Y instead of X. For instance, I need to edit a text and make a replacement only on a portion of the text which is delimited by two words. So imagine I want to replace all the forms of "dog" to "cat", but only on those "dogs" which are bewtween the word "hello". My input:

```
hello
dog
dog
dog
hello
dog
dog
```

My output:

```
hello
cat
cat
cat
hello
dog
```

My script:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $file = shift;
open my $FILE, $file or die "Usa: $0 FILENAME\n";
{       
local $/;
$file = <$FILE>;
do {$file =~ s{dog}{cat}g} until
($file =~ m/hello/);
}
print $file;
```

But I get replaced all "dogs"

I tried other stratagey:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $file = shift;
open my $FILE, $file or die "Usa: $0 FILENAME\n";
{       
local $/;
$file = <$FILE>;
while ($file =~ m{hello(.*?)hello}sg) {
my $text = $1;
$text =~ s{dog}{cat}g;
}
}
print $file;
```

But in this case I get no replacement...

Comment: What's wrong with editing line by line?  It's more memory efficient.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). Explain the problem you're actually trying to solve instead of how you're trying to solve it. Include sample input data and your expected output.

Comment: Not sure what you need exactly, but you can read line by line and still store your text in a variable, then do whatever you want with it, something like 
`while(<$f>){ $buffer .= $_; }`

Comment: You really need to explain more about what you want to achieve. If you disable line-by-line reading and then read from the file, then you have read to the the end of the file and there is nothing more to be read, in any mode. Please give an example to show what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to resort to slurping and multi-line regexes to solve this. Simply use a variable to track the state of the current line, i.e. whether you're inside or outside your delimiters:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $in_hello;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    $in_hello = ! $in_hello if $_ eq 'hello';
    s/dog/cat/ if $in_hello;
    say;
}

__DATA__
hello
dog
dog
dog
hello
dog
dog
```

#### Output:

```
hello
cat
cat
cat
hello
dog
dog
```

Comment: Ok, now it works, but I get the output in a single line, without newlines. That is: hellocatcatcatcathellodogdog. Does it have to do with the "chomp" sentence?. If I erase it, I get the same input as output

Comment: `chomp` strips the newline, so you have to use `say` (as in my example) or `print $_, "\n"`. You can't just remove the `chomp` from my example and expect it to work, since the statement `if $_ eq 'hello'` will fail if the line ends with a newline; `hello != hello\n`

Comment: Could you just explain to me the logic behind this sentence: `$in_hello = ! $in_hello if $_ eq 'hello';`

Comment: @user2837862 If line equals `hello`, then switch the variable `$in_hello` from true to false or false to true, depending on its previous value.

Answer (score 1):

Default, line by line, mode is back again outside code block:

```
{
    local $/;
    $filename = <F>;
}
```

`$/` is global variable which is [dynamically scoped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8473837/223226) in this example.