# How do I access variables in a higher stack frame in perl?

Tags: perl, stack-trace

How can I do something like this in Perl?    E.g. access $a in a function that it isn't defined in?     I don't want to use globals,  and also don't want to use a CPAN module or pass $a as a parameter to bar.

```
sub foo {
  my $a;
  bar();
}

sub bar {
  print STDOUT "a is " .  magic_function_that_looks_into_callers_frame('a');
}
```

Comment: Like this: `bar( $a )`

Comment: See also: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What's-a-closure%3f  (What's a closure?)  I don't know why you need to coerce Perl into breaking its scoping rules, but such needs usually smell of a programmer painting himself into a corner and hoping the language will bail him out.  While you could generate a version of a nested sub by assigning a subref generated inside of another sub to a typeglob, it's often better to stick to saner means.  Do read about closures; you may be able to use them effectively to solve your problem.

Comment: (supposing you have a good reason for doing that) The debugger ([perl5db.pl](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/lib/perl5db.pl)) does it, so you may be able to so something similar. Otherwise you can look into [B](https://metacpan.org/pod/B) and you also have [PadWalker](https://metacpan.org/pod/PadWalker) in CPAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is dynamic extent (i.e., the value hangs around until Perl execution is done with the subroutine which started it). Perl implements this with `local` (rather than `my`). Check out the answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8473837/2140998, but here's a small example:

```
our $foo;

sub top {
    local $foo = "top";
    bar();
}

sub bar {
    say "Called from $foo";
}

top();
```

So the (value of the) variable can be accessed from the calling stack frame, although the variable needs to actually exist globally or the code won't properly compile (Perl does like its lexical scoping).

For more advanced work, there's also: https://metacpan.org/pod/PadWalker, but that's really playing with Perl's internals, so not for normal use.

Comment: thanks,  local doesn't seem to work with "strict" in place -- is there a way around that?

Comment: Yes, that's what the "our" declaration is there for. That declares the variable enough so that strict checks work. In practice, what it does is make the variable exist lexically, without a value. The "local" then puts in a temporary value but removes that value when it leaves scope. You're not completely "accessing the variable in a higher stack frame", in that the variable is lexical (global to the file), but you are accessing its value in a higher stack frame. The difference is awkward and subtle, but it's enough to allow callbacks, etc., to access calling procedure values.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a is in bar()'s environment when its called, a way out is to call bar() with $a as an argument. For example:

```
sub bar {
  print @_;
}

sub foo {
  my $a = "what";
  bar($a);
}

foo;
```